# How to calculate needed amount for supply order?

Tags: sql

Table "*client_orders*":

| date | ordered | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28.05 | 50 | 1 |
| 23.06 | 60 | 2 |
| 24.05 | 50 | 1 |
| 25.06 | 130 | 2 |

Table "*stock*":

| id | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 | 23.04 |
| 2 | 90 | 25.04 |
| 1 | 10 | 24.04 |
| 2 | 10 | 24.06 |

I want to calculate the amount I need to order (to fulfill the stock) for what date. For instance, it should be:

- 30 by 28.05 (60+10-50-50=-30) for id = 1
- -90 by 25.06 (90-60+10-130=-90) for id = 2

I tried to do it with `LAG` function, but the problem is that the stock here is not updating.

```
SELECT *,
       SUM(amount - ordered) OVER (PARTITION BY sd.id ORDER BY d.date ASC) 
FROM      stock sd 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT date, 
                  id, 
                  ordered 
           FROM client_orders) AS d 
       ON sd.id = d.id
```

Couldn't find anything similar on the web. Grateful if you share articles/examples how to do that.

Comment: Don't tag conflicting products; just tag the technology you are *really* using.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a union of the two tables and sum all stock amounts with the negative of ordered amounts. For the date you could instead take the corresponding maximum value.

```
SELECT id,
       SUM(amount),
       MAX(date)
FROM (SELECT id,
             -ordered AS amount,
             date
      FROM client_orders
      UNION
      SELECT *
      FROM stock
     ) stock_and_orders
GROUP BY id
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/e9CsnBpJBxvnY4ZzNnkk4/1).